# How does $G\frac{\frac{1}{2}m_{1}\cdot m_{2}}{\frac{1}{4}r^2}$ become $8\left(G\frac{m_{1}\cdot m_{2}}{r^2}\right)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm busy doing a highschool physics exercise which involves some algebra, and I'm having trouble seeing how they got from one step to the next. Here's what it looks like:

$$
...\\
F_{g}=G\frac{\frac{1}{2}m_{1}\cdot m_{2}}{\frac{1}{4}r^2}\\
F_{g}=8\left(G\frac{m_{1}\cdot m_{2}}{r^2}\right)\\
...
$$

I just can't figure out how they got from the first line to the next? Like, I can factor out the $\frac{1}{2}$ from the numerator, ending up with $F_{g}=\frac{1}{2}(G\frac{m_{1}\cdot m_{2}}{\frac{1}{4}r^2})$, but I'm stuck on how to get the $\frac{1}{4}$ out of the denominator.

Here's a screenshot of it from my book. I noticed that the numerator doesn't actually have the second mass, like how I copied it over to my question, but I'm handling that as a typo lol.

[image]

P.S. I'm not sure how to tag this question. Feel free to retag it, if there's better ones.

Comment: I suspect that the $1/4 r^2$ should be $(r/4)^2$.  That is, $1/4$ in the $()$.  Please check if there is a transcription error.

Comment: @Doug I have it exactly as it is in my textbook. We're doing gravitational force of a fictional planet that has twice mass of earth but a quarter of its radius. Edit: Though now that you mention it, I do notice something else that I assume is a typo . The numerator, according to the book doesn't have the second mass. I'll just update the question with a screenshot of the book.

Comment: Then, my comment is correct: $(r/4)^2$ instead.  Use this, and you will get the factor of $8$.  The radius is squared, so the factor of $1/4$ must go inside $()$.

Comment: the second mass doesn't impact the transformation

Comment: @Conan Thanks, I figured. I just included my edit on the off chance that it *does* impact it.

Comment: what is the relation between $r_B$ and $r_E$ ?

Comment: This seems to be implying $m_B= \frac 12 m_E$ and $r_B = \frac 14 r_E$ and there's a parenthesis error.  But we have to know what the book says.  By my calculation if $r_B =\frac 14 r_E$ then $Volume_B= \frac 1{64} Volume_E$.  So if $m_B = \frac 12 m_B$ that would require that Beeble is 32 times as dense as Earth.... which is certainly possible I suppose.....

Comment: Maybe we need more of the book.  Where are the terms numbers and formulas defined.

Comment: Here's a link to the problem.  It states that planet Beeble's radius is 1/4 of Earth's.  So that 1/4 should be inside the squaring.  https://www.siyavula.com/read/science/grade-11/newtons-laws/02-newtons-laws-04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
F &=& G \frac{\frac{1}{2}M}{\frac{1}{4}r^2} \nonumber \\
&=& 1 \times G\frac{\frac{1}{2}M}{\frac{1}{4}r^2} \nonumber \\
&=& \frac{16}{16} \times G\frac{\frac{1}{2}M}{\frac{1}{4}r^2} \nonumber \\
&=& ...
\end{eqnarray}
and you won't get $8(G\frac{M}{r^2})$. Then try with $F = G \frac{\frac{1}{2}M}{(\frac{1}{4}r)^2}$.

Personally  I don't know where the error occurs, depends on the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should multiply top and bottom by $4$ to get $F_g = 2G\frac {m_1m_2}{r^2}$ so that answer seems in error.

However if the equation where $F_g =G\frac {\frac 12m_1m_2}{(\frac 14r)^2}$ you multiply top and bottom by $4^2$ to get $F_g=8\frac {m_1m_2}{r^2}$.

But the text you quote seems to imply that Beeble is a planet with have the mass of Earth.  This would imply by $r^3\sim mass$ (mass increases cubically as radius increase) so if $M_B= \frac 12 M_E$ then $r_B$ ought to be equal to $\sqrt[3]{\frac 13}r_E$ and we'd get $F_g =G\frac {M_B}{r_B^2} = G\frac {\frac 12 M_E}{(\sqrt[3]{\frac 12}r_E)^2}=G\frac{\frac 12M_E}{(\frac 12)^{\frac 23}r_E^2}=(\frac 12)^{\frac 13}\frac {M_e}{r_E^2}$.

But maybe Beeble does not have the same density as earth.  If Beeble has half the mass of Earth and half the radius as Earth (then Beeble is $8$ times as dense as Earth) then wed have $F_g =G\frac {\frac 12m_E}{(\frac 12r)^2}= 2G\frac {m_E}{r_E^2}$.

But if Beeble has half mass of Earth and $\frac 14$ the radius of Earth (then Beeble is $32$ times as dense as Earth) then we would have $F_q = G\frac {\frac 12 m_E}{(\frac 14r)^2} = 8G\frac {m_E}{r_E}$.

I imagine this last bit is what the book had in mind.  (Although I've never heard of Beeble so I don't know.)

Anyway the book is in error, but probably because it meant $(\frac 14r)^2$ instead of $\frac 14r^2$.  Parenthesis matter.... a lot.